# How to dynamically generate downstream list from task in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have a main task holding it's logic in this function

I'm not completely sure how to do this. Maybe I need another task in between? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: tasks_to_run will be pushed to xcom you can extract the list in the downstream task. If you are looking to create dynamic tasks based on that list - this is an anti pattern for Airflow.

Comment: I have tasks already made in this script. Basically, I have a first task that checks whether all these tasks meet a condition. If they do, I need to run them. If not, I need to not run them. Essentially, the downstream execution list needs to be dynamically determined based on the result of the 1st task

Comment: In your code get_campaign_active pushes to xcom the list. so if list_of_tasks will do xcom pull you will get the values you need.

Comment: So am I unable to get the return results of the get_campaign_active task unless I fetch them in another task through .xcom_pull?

Comment: Hey @nick_rinaldi I was wondering if my answer below was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you already have multiple tasks created, but you need to dynamically define which of them will follow downstream execution. If that is the case you can safely use [BranchPythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html#airflow.operators.python.BranchPythonOperator):

> It derives the PythonOperator and expects a Python function that returns a single task_id or list of task_ids to follow. The task_id(s) returned should point to a task directly downstream from {self}. All other "branches" or directly downstream tasks are marked with a state of skipped so that these paths can't move forward. The skipped states are propagated downstream to allow for the DAG state to fill up and the DAG run's state to be inferred.

Consider the following based on the [example_dag](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/example_dags/example_branch_operator.py) distributed with Airflow:

```py
with DAG(
    dag_id="branch_multiple_tasks",
    default_args=args,
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    tags=["example"],
) as dag:

    run_this_first = DummyOperator(
        task_id="run_this_first",
    )

    options = ["branch_a", "branch_b", "branch_c", "branch_d"]

    branching = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id="branching",
        python_callable=lambda: options[1:3],
    )
    run_this_first >> branching

    join = DummyOperator(
        task_id="join",
        trigger_rule="none_failed_or_skipped",
    )

    for option in options:
        t = DummyOperator(
            task_id=option,
        )

        dummy_follow = DummyOperator(
            task_id="follow_" + option,
        )

        # Label is optional here, but it can help identify more complex branches
        branching >> Label(option) >> t >> dummy_follow >> join
```

In this example the `python_callable` passed to `branching` task is hardcoded to return `['branch_b', 'branch_c']`.
You could provide your own callable and return a list of `tasks_id`'s as string,  based on any criteria. You could even use your `get_campaign_active` function as long as you return the expected format. Maybe it's cleaner if you create a new function and perform `xcom_pull` from the previous one. I guess it's up to your needs.

Graph view:

[image: graph_view_of_the_example]

Let me know if that worked for you!

Comment: Hey, appreciate the answer. I found the solution, and I have to have a bunch of tasks running in parallel branching off of one main task.